# Permutation even number next to odd number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

S = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

How many permutations are there of the set S where 2 is next to at least 1 odd number?

---

I know that this is could map to a 2 to 1 bijection and it would be 360 if the question were asking such that each even number is next to at least one odd number. I'm unsure what to do to make it work for a specific even number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: 2 is at the head of the set $S$. Then there must be one odd number besides 2. So there are $4\times 5!=480$ choices.

Case 2: 2 is at the tail of the set S. There are also $4\times 5!=480$ choices.

Case 3: 2 is in the middle. 2 can be at the rest five places. Fix the place of 2. Then the choices are permuting all the other numbers - 2 is surrounded by two even numbers = $6!-2\times 4!=672$.

So the total permutation are $480+480+672\times 5=4320$.